# layout_margin affects top only?

Tags: android, layout

`android:layout_margin` or `android:padding` does affect all four directions?

It looks like it sets 'top' and 'left'. 
Couldn't find the doc to confirm.

Comment: can you post some relevant code?

Comment: Yes of course. It affects all 4 directions.
See [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:padding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:padding)

Comment: yes, it affects all margins. Post your XML here, maybe there are another attributes that affect your layout.

Comment: post your xml ccode, it does affect all 4 sides.

Comment: Put the xml here....it affects all 4 sides for sure

Comment: can you post your xml code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it affects all sides.

`android:layout_margin`  - Specifies extra space on the left, top, right and bottom sides of the view.

`android:padding` - Sets the padding, in pixels, of all four edges.

I think there is an error in your `xml` file.